# Normalising a table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, normalization, normalize

Was wondering if someone could assist in providing some guidance as to how I could most efficiently normalize the following table so that I can create a refreshable view / table.

Table1:

```
SYSTEM_KEY | ID | ORDER | ORDER_STATUS | SYSTEM_Actions
A             1   Pencil   Open          Shipped   
B             1   Pencil   Open          Tested  
C             1   Pencil   Open          Shipped    
A             1   Paper    Closed        Delivered
```

I'am looking to normalize this table in a repeatable way to something like this:

RESULT:

```
ID | ORDER | Order Status | A_actions | B_Actions | C_Actions 
1    Pencil  OPEN           Shipped     Tested      Delivered                   
1    Paper   Closed         Delivered    null       null
```

I was able to achieve this by doing something similar to this

```
Select full.ID, full.order, full.orderstatus, case when system_ID = 'A' then sysa.system_actions as A_actions, ....{for B, C} 
from table1 full
left join table1 sysa on full.id = sysa.id and full.order = sysa.order
left join table1 sysb on full.id = sysb.id and full.order = sysb.order
```

Whilst this appeared to work, it was quite clunky in terms of being repeatable having to use several staging tables.

Does anyone know if a good way I can achieve this?

Comment: look up PIVOT or MODEL or SUM(CASE ... ). you must hundreds of examples in this alone.

Comment: That's not normalization.  In fact it's even less normalized than the original table.

Comment: What you're proposing is to DENORMALIZE the table by adding a repeating group of actions.  Maybe you should think about this.  Your proposed change will make the table harder to process, will cause code to handle it to be more complex and error-prone, will call down the wrath of the gods upon your head and your descendants for seven generations, and will likely cause the end of the world as we know it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try using group by clause

```
select id,order,order_status,
       case when system_ID = 'A' then system_actions as A_actions,
       case when system_ID = 'B' then system_actions as B_actions,
       case when system_ID = 'C' then system_actions as C_actions
from table1
group by id,order,order_status
```